# Datastructures to improve the performance of text matching

Tags: performance, algorithm, nlp, time-complexity, categorization

I am working on categorizing some text into a category that suites to the text the most. As a first step, I am writing a simple text matching code.
I am comparing words in a piece of text from a text set to words which indicate some categories.

The complexity of this simple search becomes too big O(n^4)!

Text : Many Hollywood movies are fantastic. Cinema lovers are addicted to them. ( n words in 1 sentence and m such sentences)

Categories could be: Movie, Songs, Sports etc. ( p categories each with x words)

Indicator words for movie-[movie, cinema, film ... ] (x words for one category)

So, the search time becomes O (m *n * p * x) which could be too big.

Can you suggest me some datastructure/ method to solve simplify the complexity?

Answer (score 1):

There is an algorithm called `Aho–Corasick string matching algorithm` based on trie, and for one category, it can check whether the word in the category is appear in the Text.

You can build p tries, and It will perform better than O(m * n * p * x). (I think will be O(p * m * (n + x) ) )

Here is [Aho–Corasick_string_matching_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm)